# Copy current selection & URL and paste into Excel?

Tags: automation, applescript

The script I'm trying to make has to:

1. copy current selection and URL in Safari
2. paste selection in cell1
3. paste URL in cell2
4. go to a new line below cell1 in Excel

How can this be done with AppleScript?

I've started with this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theURL to URL of front document
    set theText to (do JavaScript "(''+getSelection())" in document 1)
end tell


tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set value of active cell to the theURL
end tell
```

but I don't know how to *navigate* to adjacent cells with AppleScript.

**adamh**'s code does this perfectly:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theURL to URL of front document
    set theText to (do JavaScript "(''+getSelection())" in document 1)
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set foundRange to find range "A:A" what "" -- finds the first empty cell in column A
    set the value of foundRange to theText      
    -- Work out its adjacent cell in same row
    set cur_col to the first column index of foundRange
    set cur_row to the first row index of foundRange
    set nextCell to cell cur_row of column (cur_col + 1)
    set value of nextCell to theURL
    select cell (cur_row + 1) of column cur_col -- select the next logical cell
end tell
```

Comment: Why do you need this exactly? Would it be sufficient to write the URL to a tab-delimited text file, which can be imported into Excel? Do you have any code that you tried yourself? (When you post here, you should show at least a minimal understanding of coding).

Comment: I need to save some quotes with their source URLs, but I can't navigate between cells in Excel.

Comment: Please, answer my question, if you want any help.

Comment: When I highlight text in a browser window, I want to copy the selection, copy the current the URL and paste them separately in two adjacent cells in Excel. The procedure will be repeated so moving to a new row in Excel after each paste is essential. A text file that will convert each quote/url pair to a distinct row will work, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this ago, based on your above code.

It works by finding the first empty cell in column A for the insertion point.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set theURL to URL of front document
    set theText to (do JavaScript "(''+getSelection())" in document 1)
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set foundRange to find range "A:A" what "" -- finds the first empty cell in column A
    set the value of foundRange to theText      
    -- Work out its adjacent cell in same row
    set cur_col to the first column index of foundRange
    set cur_row to the first row index of foundRange
    set nextCell to cell cur_row of column (cur_col + 1)
    set value of nextCell to theURL
    select cell (cur_row + 1) of column cur_col -- select the next logical cell
end tell
```

Comment: Look at my original post to see how I've used your code. I need to set the active cell to the first cell of the next row at the end of the operation in order not to overwrite the previous entry. I tried _set active cell to_, but it doesn't seem to work. Ideas?

Comment: @user1891836: My solution avoids using the active cell by finding the first empty cell in column A.  It does what you have asked for, starting a new row every time the script is run without overwriting any data. Give it a go and see it in action.

Comment: it works as it should. I just wonder why there is no way to move the current selection (i.e. active cell)...

Comment: ok i get it now, i just modified my answer above with extra line to do that.

Comment: perfect. it now selects the next logical cell :)